# Converting data frame column values to float type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, data-science

My dataset has two columns, 'A' and 'B,' both of which have percentage values but are of the object datatype. For example,

| A% | B% |
| --- | --- |
| 1.x% | 3.x% |
| 2.x% | 4.x% |

Goal: I'm mostly interested in using this for machine learning clustering, hence my goal is to convert it to decimal form. For example, convert the '1.2%' object value to a float value of 0.012.

I tried two methods: the first was successful, but it took a long time.

1. I removed or stripped the object % from say '34%' using pandas.Series.str.strip to '34' obj and then converted this value to float using .to_numeric() --> 34. Now I divided this value with 100 and got the result 0.34.
2. However, in the second way I was attempting the below,

The function:

```
def Tab_to_float(z):
    return float(z.strip('%'))/100
```

Now when I pass the column (which is an object) as below:

```
Tab_to_float(df['A'])
```

I get error:

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'strip'

I tried feeding this function an int, float, numpy array, and even a dataframe, but I got the same error: 'that' object has no attribute'strip'. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Is there a better way to deal with such requirements? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You need to use `.str` accessor since you are passing an entire series. i.e. `z.str.strip('%')`. But another issues is, if the actual value contains `x` then it can not be converted to float.

Comment: Thank you @ThePyGuy, I put z.str.strip but it still gives me error: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>. Also I just put the x value as an example (sorry for the confusion!) - it is like numeric values 25.2%, 65.35% etc. x as in any value there.

Comment: `return float(z.strip('%'))/100` -> `return z.str.rstrip('%').astype(float)/100`?

Comment: Thank you @Ch3steR! This works! Really appreciate you help. Could you please explain how does astype( ) helps here?

Comment: [`.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) converts your data to desired `dtype`.

Comment: Thank you @Ch3steR I get the idea now! Thank you all for your help, I'm also trying out the below answers as well. Can't upvote I dont have the points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['A'] = df.apply(lambda row : Tab_to_float(row['A']), axis = 1)
```

You can do this for these two columns and then you can apply this function.

We are applying a function along an axis of the DataFrame. (Here we are changing each element of a column). We are not changing anything for the `Tab_to_float` function in this solution.

```
data = {
        'A':['34.3%', '24%'],
        'B':['32%','33%'] }
 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

 
df['A'] = df.apply(lambda row : Tab_to_float(row['A']), axis = 1)
df['B'] = df.apply(lambda row : Tab_to_float(row['B']), axis = 1)

print(df)
```

Outputs:

```
       A     B
0  0.343  0.32
1  0.240  0.33
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it a bit interesting, here is a snippet to convert all columns ending in '%' from text percentage format to float:

```
for col in df.filter(regex='.*%'):   # if column name ends in '%'
    df[col] = df[col].str.rstrip('%').astype(float).div(100) # remove %, convert to float, divide by 100
    df.rename(columns={col: col.rstrip('%')}, inplace=True)  # remove the '%' in the column name
```

output:

```
       A      B
0  0.011  0.033
1  0.022  0.044
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lambda operator to apply your functions to the pandas data frame or to the series. you ca convert each element on a column to a floating point number and divide by 100, like this:

```
(df['A']).apply(lambda x: float(x.strip('%'))/100)
```